# How can I expand one item inside a list view but not all of them (Not using ExpandListView)?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have a simple listview, each item can be selected by a simple touch. All is very simple until now.
But one of these items, somewhere in the list, on a touch, must show news items as a sublist and then a second touch on the same item must hide/collapse the sublist.

Like this :

- item1
- item2
- item3 >
- item4

After a touch on item3 :

- item1
- item2
- item3 <

  - item 31
  - item 32
  - item 33
- item4

It exists ExpandListView but I don't think that it could be ok here.
Another way could be add/remove items from the ArrayList object and then call NotifyDataSetChanged, but it's not very fun.
So, what is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

use expendable list  view in that case.

Comment: But with ExpandableListView,in my example, item1, item2 and item3 can't be "normal" row but must be header (?)

Answer (score 1):

At least two ways

```
1) Add them to the touched view hierarchy on clicked and remove after second click
2) Add views to the xml, make VISIBILITY.GONE and change visibility on click events
```

Comment: I can't use simple views since the number of items is dynamic. I think this solution will be more complicated to build. Moreover I will lost all the properties of a list view component.

Comment: ExpandableListView with dynamic viewtype is the way to go then

Answer (score 0):

You should look [Advanced RecyclerView](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) library. You can find all combination of list view.